# Does I need to use HTML Purifier If I'm stripping tags/converting them to HTML entities?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm current working on a project where data is read from a textarea and fed to a mysql database.  My question is do I really need to use html purifier to prevent mysql injections or whatever attacks if I'm already stripping html tags or converting them to entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add escaping quotes `'` (`addslashes` php function).

Comment: That is useless unless injecting inside a block of javascript or inside a javascript event handler. You need to do a hell of a lot more than this to be safe from XSS. Please take the time to read the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet and preferably read up on Cross-site scripting https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 2):

To protect against mysql injections you should use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

For other attacks, well for XSS you need to do proper output escaping. That is a bit more of a piece of cake. Matt Robinson wrote a [good introduction to the concept](http://inanimatt.com/php-output-escaping.html). Pádraic Brady points out that [it isn't as simple as that](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/) and eventually proposes to use a wrapper around htmlspecialchars like [Twig](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L772) do. Zend also has an escaping library and they are both inspired on the reference code from [ESAPI](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/) which unfortunately does not have a [production ready version for php](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=PHP).

Note that all libraries [let the comma pass through in javascript context](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/765) which I think is a vulnerability.

**If you don't want to accept html input** and you are OK with just stripping out the html tags, **you don't need to use an html purifier**.